# Trying to Set Password in Webpart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, active-directory, password

I created a webpart where I am trying to set the password (if forgotten). Below is the code I am using: I get an access denied even though I am impersonating with an account that is in the Administrators group.

```
SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
string userName, domainName;
// Get the user token for the specified user, domain, and password using the 
// unmanaged LogonUser method. 
// The local machine name can be used for the domain name to impersonate a user on this machine.


const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
//This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token. 
const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

// Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token. 
bool returnValue = LogonUser(username, domain, password,
LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);

if (false == returnValue)
{
    int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
}
using (safeTokenHandle)
{
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
{
string x = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, username);
up.SetPassword(txtNewChangedPassword.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change user password in sharepoint.

If you are trying to change the password of an fba user you can use the ChangePassword method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepassword.aspx) of the MembershipUser class.

By other way if you want to change it in AD, you have to invoke the ChangePassword method of a DirectoryEntry object of User type:
user.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { oldPassword, newPassword });
(check this post: http://glorix.blogspot.com/2007/10/ad-change-password-webpart.html)

greetings :)

Comment: I'm trying to Set the password in AD.